# dialog box to send url to different app

Tags: android

When I click share icon on Google PlayStore it automatically opens the option of various applications like WhatsApp, Skype, Facebook to send URL.

Is there any code or widget to have the same accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at  `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.

With a little googling you will find many code examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common behavior. The share button associated with lots of apps on Android. So, it is part of their code.